# Obtaining coordinates of a point using pcd_viewer?

Tags: ros, pcl, perception-pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using pcd_viewer to visualize a point cloud.

```
rosrun pcl_visualization pcd_viewer <some-pcd-file>
```

I'd like to find the coordinates of single points. Is there any quick way to select the points in the graphical tool?

I know that you can toggle some options via keystrokes and on the command-line. I wonder whether I just missed this feature or whether it's implemented.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9524/obtaining-coordinates-of-a-point-using-pcd_viewer?/) by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 960 on 2011-03-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately you can't get the coordinate of a single point using pcd_viewer in pcl_visualization.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1